# Firebase Function deploy build fails but predeploy succeeded

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a react.js project with Firebase functions configured in a sub-folder: root/functions.
The functions are written in typescript and have paths option configured in tsconfig.json.
In my functions/index.ts file I import multiple files from all over the project, not only from the functions directory.

I have deployed my functions successfully multiple times.

Now the functions build successfully but fail when deploying.
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@/custom/file' or its corresponding type declarations.
I get this error for all 8 custom files that I import.

The confusing part is that the function builds without a problem locally but only fails when Firebase tries to update the function remotely.

versions:

- firebase: ^9.19.1
- firebase-admin: ^11.6.0
- firebase-functions: ^3.23.0
- firebase-tools: 11.16.0

Comment: I had the same problem.. and I can see that my types were successfully transpiled into the lib folder of the functions sub-project but to my surprise Firebase does not find them when deploying.
I ended up doing a workaround: Just copied to the types from my root project into the functions sub-project. It works, but it is not a clean solution tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the exact same problem. All Firebase functions just all of a sudden fail to deploy with TS2307: Cannot find module errors.

What finally worked was updating to the latest version of the Firebase CLI:
`npm i -g firebase-tools@latest`